# Laravel Delete Route 404 Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Why am I trying to remove the product from the wishlist, I get a 404 error?

In my home.php, I have this:

```
Route::prefix('profile')->middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('', [ProfileController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/twofactor', [ProfileController::class, 'manageTwoFactor']);
    Route::post('/twofactor', [ProfileController::class, 'activeTwoFactor']);
    Route::get('/twofactor/phone',[ProfileController::class,'getPhoneNumberVerify'])->name('profile.2fa.phone');
    Route::post('/twofactor/phone',[ProfileController::class,'postPhoneNumberVerify']);
    Route::get('/orders',[OrderController::class,'index']);
    Route::get('/orders/{order}',[OrderController::class,'show'])->name('order.details');
    Route::get('/orders/{order}/payment',[OrderController::class,'payment'])->name('profile.order.payment');
    Route::resource('/wishlist',WishlistController::class)>except(['show','create','update','edit']);}); //wishlist routes
```

In my controller I have this:

```
 public function destroy(Wishlist $wishlist)
{
    $wishlist->delete();
    return back();
}
```

### form:

```
               <div class="flex-grow-one">
                    <form action="{{route('wishlist.destroy',$wish->product_id)}}" 
                       method="post" id="delete-wish-{{$wish->product_id}}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('delete')
                    </form>
                    <a href="javascript:" onclick="document.getElementById('delete-wish- 
                      {{$wish->product_id}}').submit();" class="remove-favorite">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
              </div>
```

Comment: Try running `php artisan route:list` and see the route for destroy

Comment: probably `$wishlist` of `Wishlist` model not found, so its throw a 404 error

Comment: I have done this and there is destroy route

Answer (score 0):

Your wishlist should something like /profile/wishlist/{wishlist}
So in this case delete redirect back to this wishlist but you already delete that so it will show 404. You have show probably use some index there or retirect to another route.

route('profile.wishlist.index');

Then it will show index which you can configure to show all wishlist or you can do it you own way.

Comment: My problem is solved, I had to put  $wish->id  instead of  $wish->product_id

Answer (score 0):

Because at the end you go back to the previous page and the previous page was deleted to the element and. No longer available

```
public function destroy(Wishlist $wishlist)
{
    $wishlist->delete();
    return back();
}
```